# Spatialite equivalent of ST_MakeBox2D?

Tags: postgis, spatialite

I'm a GIS newbie. I'm porting an app that uses PostGIS to SpatiaLite and wonder what the SpatiaLite equivalent of ST_MakeBox2D might be. Can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BuildMbr(minx, miny, maxx, maxy, <SRID>)`

Comment: Thanks Micha. Dunno if it's working yet, but it's not throwing exceptions any longer.